# Keep historical stack trace of nodejs app running on heroku

Tags: node.js, logging, heroku, express, loggly

- I have a nodejs (express) app running on heroku.
- I need to keep a short history of logs (up to a day or so).
- I need to be able to dig in to the stack trace of any errors being thrown

I have been able to solve the first two by using Loggly but I can't find any solution which will show me the stack trace of any exceptions which have been thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `node-airbrake` [module](https://github.com/felixge/node-airbrake) on your app, connecting either to the [webservice](https://airbrake.io/) or to an own set-up server-instance for the notification backend using `errbit` [gem](https://github.com/errbit/errbit).

For setting things up, it depends, which way you want to go.
To keep it simple, i'd recommend using the 30-day free-trial hosted service and in case, you're happy with it, to setup your own `errbit` instance.

Comment: thanks, i think i'll try and get my own errbit server running...really helpful :)